# TextBox values inside a loop

Tags: vba, loops, textbox

Please i need your help, i have a problem with the next code, i want to write in different cells all the values that user enters, in the `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` i only write 3 of them, but i can´t do that even the fist value appears, only appears an error:

> object doesn´t support this property or method.

```
Dim Label1 As Object
Dim txtB1 As Control

For NL = 1 To NumeroLineas
    Set txtB1 = UserForm2.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "TxtBx" & NL, True)

    With txtB1
        .Name = "TxtBx" & NL
        .Height = 25.5
        .Width = 150
        .Left = 150
        .Top = 18 * NL * 2
    End With    
Next NL
UserForm2.Show

'This is UserForm2
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Cells(10, 10) = Controls.TxtBx1.Value
    Cells(10, 11) = Controls.TxtBx2.Value
    Cells(10, 12) = Controls.TxtBx3.Value
End sub
```

Comment: You are the expert regarding your case and you know everything about it. Please do not assume that other people also have the full knowledge of it.
Please be more specific and detailed: What do you want to acheive? What is working already? What is not working like it should? What are the error messages?

Answer (score 0):

You have to address the code-generated controls like this: `Controls.Item("ControlName").Value`

So the following should work:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Cells(10, 10) = Controls("TxtBx1").Value
    Cells(10, 11) = Controls("TxtBx2").Value
    Cells(10, 12) = Controls("TxtBx3").Value

    'This works too
    'Cells(10, 10) = Controls.Item("TxtBx1").Value
End sub
```

Furthermore the setting of the `Textbox.Name`-property is redundant.
This line is not required:

```
.Name = "TxtBx" & NL
```